# ASP.NET не видит ни одного файла в папке Views/Home

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Пишу проект на ASP .NET MVC 4
В папке View\Home есть изображение bg.jpg
но при попытке к нему обратиться http://localhost:14066/Home/bg.jpg происходит HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
и естественно этот код не работает:

```
<style> .body { background-image: url("bg.jpg"); } </style>
```

И еще я пытаюсь подключить внешний  css но он тоже не подключается хотя находится в одной папке с index. Как быть?

Comment: Статичные файлы лежат в static папке, переместите изображение и стили туда.

Comment: Добавил в папку Home папку static, но ничего не изменилось, по прежнему при обращении http://localhost:14066/static/bg.jpg выдает 404

Comment: если не ошибаюсь должно быть localhost:14066/bg.jpg

Comment: не работает, хотя bg.jpg уже везде

Comment: возможности нет проверить и запустить проект. На работе и под убунтой :) почитайте тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949460/how-do-you-request-static-html-files-under-the-views-folder-in-asp-net-mvc поищите StaticFileHandler в конфигах, если нет пропишите (примеры можно найти в гугле).

Comment: создал папку content в проекте и файлы в этой папке доступны при обращении из браузера на прямую, но теперь не пойму как ссылаться из представления на эти файлы? Пробовал так:
"content/bg.jpg"
ничего не выходит...

Comment: все ок решил,написал "content/bg.jpg" а надо  "content/bg.jpg"
Спасибо!

Comment: оформите как ответ, может кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статичные файлы должны хранится в папке проекта в директории content

Есть еще большая статья на эту тему:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files

хотя вся суть в том что надо:
1) в методе BuildWebHost добавить .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())

так в статье:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

А так у меня:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .Build();
```

2) добавить в метод public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) :

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

После чего все что вы положите в папку wwwroot у вас будет доступно

Comment: И подключать их лучше через `@Url.Content("~/content/bg.jpg")`, иначе не будет работать на всех страницах, кроме `/` (или как `~/content/bg.jpg`, но работает не везде).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> .body { background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/bg.jpg")"); } </style>
```

Comment: вот именно для того, чтобы так не делали, в Views/web.config вписан `<add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>`

Answer (score 0):

все дело в обработке маршрутов, когда вы добавляете файл в Home, дефолтный обработчик маршрутов пытается сопоставить запрос с маршрутом, и ничего не находит

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Допустим, вы добавили папку Public с необходимым контентом, чтобы обработчик игнорил все папки и файлы внутри него, нужно что-то вроде

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Public/{all}");
```